# How to change key name of JSON object via vue js

Tags: vue.js, v-for, v-model

I have some problems with changing key names "User1" and "User2" of the JSON object with vue.

```
myJSON = {"User1": {"damage": "10000"}, "User2": {"damage": "10000"}}
users = ["User1","User2","User3","User4"]
```

This is code of loop, and some comments. Actually problem is I can't use "key" in v-model...

```
<div class="mb-3" v-for="(item, key, index) in myJSON">
 <el-select v-model="key" filterable placeholder="Select"> // This is doesn't work - it's my problem =)
  <el-option
   v-for="cl in users"
   :key="cl"
   :label="cl"
   :value="cl">
  </el-option>
 </el-select>
 <el-input-number v-model="item.damage"></el-input-number> // It's okey, damage is changing.
</div>
```

I have already tried to change v-model on:

```
v-model="item.key" // JSON after this
myJSON = {"User1": {"damage": "10000", "key": "User3"}, "User2": {"damage": "10000", "key": "User4"}}

v-model="myJSON[key]" // Have error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'myJSON' of undefined

v-model="myJSON[key]" // Same
TypeError: Cannot read property 'myJSON' of undefined
```

After select user in `<el-select>` i need smth like this:

```
{"User2": {"damage": "10000"}, "User3": {"damage": "10000"}}
```

Or

```
{"User3333": {"damage": "10000"}, "User312321": {"damage": "10000"}}
```

But I'm on the not right way, please help.

Comment: why `mysql` in the tag?

Comment: It is not clear what result you want to achieve. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you can directly change an obj's key with v-model, but there is a workaround.

```
<div id="app">
 <ol>
  <li v-for="(item, index) in myJSON_format2">
   {{item}}
   <input v-model="item.damage"/>
   <input v-model="item.key"/>
  </li>
 </ol>
</div>

new Vue({
 el: "#app",
 data: {
  myJSON: {"User1": {"damage": "10000"}, "User2": {"damage": "10000"}},
  myJSON_format2: []
 },
 methods: {
  change_myJSON_toFormat2 () {
    for (let i in this.myJSON) {
     this.myJSON_format2.push({ damage: this.myJSON[i].damage, key: i })
    }
  }
 },
 created () {
  this.change_myJSON_toFormat2()
 }
})
```

Pls check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/shivampesitbng/dync94kt/24/

- Workaround:

  1. Changed the ds of myjson to array of obj
  2. looped the arr with v-for in vue-template
  3. changed the "user" key as you were changing "damage" key.